# Cannot run servlet on Tomcat 6

Tags: servlets, tomcat6

I just started learning servlet, by reading [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html). Problem occured every time I try to run the project

> Publishing failed with multiple errors
>
> Error copying file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF: Permission denied
>
> Error copying file WEB-INF/classes/com/anta40/filecounter/servlets/FileCounter.class: Permission denied
>
> Error copying file WEB-INF/classes/com/anta40/filecounter/FileDAO.class: Permission denied
>
> Error copying file WEB-INF/web.xml: Permission denied

I'm still confused about those permission denieds.
Why can't Eclipse copy those files?

I assume those are the ones which located in ~/workspace/filecounter/WebContent, right?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea where you store your files, but it's likely reading the files is allowed, but writing in the destination directory or overwriting files in the destination directory is not allowed.

Comment: Hmmm... is the destination directory /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps? I already chmoded 777'ed it, and still didn't work. OK, chmod 777 maybe not a good idea, but at least it's not on production server.

Comment: @anta40 But /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps doesn't appear in your error messages? Did you chomd recursively? If not it won't help. For development I think it's just better to put tomcat in your $HOME. Another solution would be to include your user in the tomcat group and set permissions accordingly. Or you may build with Maven and invoke mvn tomcat:run (in which case Maven takes care of everything for you), or even simpler; load Jetty in main() and have Jetty run your stuff. Just google "run jetty from main" or something.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the problem went away when I changed my file permissions. In addition to this, my tomcat directory was owned by root, so I had to change the owner as well. I executed this in the tomcat directory.

Eg: sudo chown -R  *